# Correct way to add index letters to TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, indexing

First a MWS and its output are as follows.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{book}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.mst}
headings_flag 1 %
heading_prefix "{\\bfseries "
    heading_suffix "}\\nopagebreak\n"
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{headings_flag}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\index{And}
\index{Book}
\index{Summer}
\index{Latex}

\pagebreak

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Index}
\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Since I want to add the index letters to TOC, then I add `\\addcontentsline{toc}{section}` to the `heading_prefix` as follows.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{book}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.mst}
headings_flag 1 %
heading_prefix "{\\bfseries\\addcontentsline{toc}{section} "
    heading_suffix "}\\nopagebreak\n"
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{headings_flag}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\index{And}
\index{Book}
\index{Summer}
\index{Latex}

\pagebreak

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Index}
\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

As you see, the index letters occur in TOC in normal face, and no in "Index" any more. **So is there any correct way to make the index letters**

1. **occur in TOC in normal face, while still**
2. **in "Index" in bold face?**

Comment: By the way, if you are unhappy with the warning message about overwriting produced by `filecontents`, you may consider getting rid of them via `\WarningFilter{latex}{Writing or overwriting file}` using the package `silence`. I'm not sure if this is the best way, but at least this works, and I've been using this dirty trick in my document class since a few months ago.

Comment: @Jinwen It's better to have `[overwrite]` since we needn't to delete the temporary files when to compile the `'.tex` file again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a new command to process the `heading_suffix` (see the `\AddIndexLetterToTOC` below), and use it in your `.mst` file.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{book}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\newcommand{\AddIndexLetterToTOC}[1]{\textbf{#1}\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.mst}
headings_flag 1 %
heading_prefix "\\AddIndexLetterToTOC{"
    heading_suffix "}\\nopagebreak\n"
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Test chapter}

\index{And}
\index{Book}
\index{Summer}
\index{Latex}

\pagebreak

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Index}
\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]